# "div" validation with jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays, duplicates

I made some columns using div and filled in the cells with sub divs.
What I want to do is only one cell can be selected per column,

```
$('div.kim2bb').on('click', function(){
    el.push($(this).attr('id'));
    console.log(el);
    parent.push($(this).parent().attr('id'));
    console.log(parent);
});
```

when the parent array gets duplicate member, I want to replace the former with the latter of same parent in el array.

```
<div id="a0" class="kim2b">
    <div id="a1" class="kim2bb">Incompetent</div>
    <div id="a2" class="kim2bb">Incapable</div>
    <div id="a3" class="kim2bb">Disabled</div>
    <div id="a4" class="kim2bb">Not adult</div>
    <div id="a5" class="kim2bb">None above</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do u mean **duplicate member**?

Comment: array member that has same value within array

Comment: could u paste ur HTML here?

Comment: i did. but didn't know if it helps

Comment: ul have multiple elements with class `.kim2b` in ur html right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to store all parent ids and last selected child div from each parent. I suggest doing it with single JS object like so:

```
var selects = {};
$('div.kim2bb').on('click', function(){
    selects[$(this).parent().attr('id')] = $(this).attr('id')
    for (var key in selects) {
      if (selects.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key + " -> " + selects[key]);
      }
    }
});
```

You can  test it here: http://jsfiddle.net/qXSPr/2/

Comment: awesome, well I made it with another solution

Answer (score 1):

Consider doing it this way. You can have an array which maps both `parent` and `child` in a key-value pair:

```
var elGroups = [];

$('div.kim2bb').on('click', function () {
    var parent = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    var element = $(this).attr('id');
    elGroups[parent] = element;
    console.log(elGroups);
});
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/hungerpain/JKHuR/

Comment: nice idea :D I thought this way too not knowing how to implement :)

Comment: I foorgot to post the answer then i remembered that i didnt :D